# How do I change the Lilypond title font?

Tags: lilypond

This should be fairly simple but I'm getting lost in instructions. What is the easiest way to change the font for the tune title only? I don't want to change the whole family of fonts for the whole sheet.

The font I'd like to use is MuseScore's Edwin. If I use the paper block to change the font name to "Edwin", the font is not found. I assume I'd have to specify the path to it.

Answer (score 5):

Seems to be resolved with \markup and \override, plus specifying the font path:

```
#(ly:font-config-add-directory "D:/fonts/MuseScore/")

\header {
  title = \markup { \override #'((font-name . "Edwin") (font-size . 6)) "My Tune" }
}
```

This works. The code can be extracted into a function, and/or into a separate file:

```
customTitle = #(define-scheme-function
  (title) (markup?)
  #{
     \markup { \override #'((font-name . "Edwin") (font-size . 6)) #title }
  #})
```

which is then included and used as:

```
\header {
    title = \customTitle "My Aria"
}
```

As Abou Samra Jean suggests, it is also possible to create a markup function as

```
\markup edwin = \markup \override #'((font-name . "Edwin") (font-size . 6)) \etc
```

which is then used

```
title = \markup \edwin "My Title"
```

Comment: The parser and location arguments are useless in current versions and deprecated. Just remove them. You can even write that function in a very concise way: `\markup edwin = \markup \override #'((font-name . "Edwin") (font-size . 6)) \etc`.